# Fetching a data text from API response and presenting it in a chat with React

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have a chat UI in react in which the user should input text and receive some data from an API response service. The UI works fine and the user text is presented in the chat but the response from the API which received in JSON format doesn't presented in the chat at all (not even an error message from the API, which should appear in the 'message' field,which is the same field where the result should be presented).As far As I know I configured everything ok, I don't know if something is messing in the render method though.

Note: the preconfigured messages at the chat state in the beginning are just for testing purposes.

The Fetch operation in under the componentDidUpdate() method at the first block of code that I posted.

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";

import Message from "./Message.js";

class Chatroom extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      chats: [
        {
          username: "clientUser",
          content: <p>Hello World!</p>,
          img:
            "http://***.jpg"
        },
        {
          username: "user2",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is user2.What's up ??</p>

        },
        {
          username: "user3",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is user3.What's up ??</p>
        },
        {
          username: "user4",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is user4.What's up ??</p>
        },
        {
          username: "userN",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is userN.What's up ??</p>,
          img: "http://***.jpg"
        },
        {
          username: "user5",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is user5.What's up ??</p>
        },
        {
          username: "user6",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is user6.What's up ??</p>
        },
        {
          username: "user7",
          content: <p>Hi,my name is user7.What's up ??</p>
        }
      ]
    };

    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBot();

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBot();


    fetch(
      "https://****",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          inputText: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>
        })
      }
    ).then(response => response.json())
      .then(parsedJSON =>
        parsedJSON.results.map((
          user
        ) => ({

          username: "BotResponse",
          content: `${user.message}',
          img: "http://***.jpg"
        }))
      )
      .then(chats =>
        this.setState({
          chats
        })
      )
      .catch(error => console.log("parsing failed", error));


  }

  scrollToBot() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chats).scrollTop = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
      this.refs.chats
    ).scrollHeight;
  }
```

The submit message method:

```
submitMessage(e) {

        e.preventDefault();




        this.setState(
          {
            chats: this.state.chats.concat([

              {
                username: "clientUser",

                content: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>,

                img: "http://***.jpg"
              }


            ])
          },
          () => {

            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value = "";
          }

        );


      }
```

The render method:

```
  render() {

    const username = "clientUser";
    const { chats } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="chatroom">
        <h3>
          Title
        </h3>

        <ul className="chats" ref="chats">
          {chats.map((
            chat //Defines message component
          ) => (
            <Message chat={chat} user={username} />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <form className="input" onSubmit={e => this.submitMessage(e)}>
          <input type="text" ref="msg" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chatroom;
```

Comment: Why not just issue the POST request during `submitMessage` since you already have the value in hand? It seems redundant to `setState` on `submitMessage`, then `setState` again once the API call returns. Also, put some `console.log` statements in each of your `then` clauses to ensure you're getting back exactly what you're expecting.

Comment: Do you mean moving the fetch operation before the "this.setState" in submitMessage(e) ?, I tried it without success.The response data still doesn't appear in the chat. Is there something I should change ?.

Comment: It's not entirely necessary to move the call to `fetch` call to `submitMessage`, it's just that you're getting the value off of `ref` twice, when you have it already in hand. But don't worry about that for now. If you put a `console.log(chats)` in your final `then` - does it log the message?

Comment: It says that chats (that inside the console.log) is not defiend

Comment: There's your problem - you need to determine why the API call, or your transformations after the fact are resulting in the `undefined`

Comment: But why it should be defined? , after I close the then with ) we are out of the scope in which chats is defined aren't we ?

Comment: Why do you think it should be `undefined`? And you're not out of score, you are chaining your API response via each `then`, the end result is you should have a valid `chat` array when you finally `setState` - if you think it _should_ be `undefined`, then why the hell are you setting `state.chats` to `undefined`, and then expecting `this.state.chats.map` in render to work?

Comment: I didn't expect it to be undefined, I just "wondered"..

Comment: Just seen that you wrap your body.inputText into a <p> tag. If that's not a typo here and you have the same stuff in your code, here's the error 

Comment: The problem is in the "results" after ParsedJSON "Cannot read property 'results' of undefined", before that I do get the JSON from the API.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way you think. You are thinking like if you were writing plain HTML with JS enhancements. React is a fundamental concept shift. You need to forget a lot of what you knew from regular, vanilla JS, to learn React. In React, you don't get HTMLElement's to do operations but rather work with local/global state and component props to declare your UI. The resulting code is more performant, maintainable and glitch-free.

To get back to your actual issue, you shouldn't be using `ref` to get the value of your input. Instead, use `onChange` to set state of your message and retrieve it later when needed.

For example:

```
export class MessageComposer extends React.Component {

  state = {
    fields: {
      message: ""
    }
  }

  clearField = fieldName => {
    this.setState({
      fields: {
        [fieldName]: ""
      }
    })
  }

  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      fields: {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }

  sendMessage = () => {
    const { fields: { message } } = this.state

    // Here you send the message contained into `message`.
    console.log(message)

    // Then you clean the message input value.
    this.clearField("message")
  }

  render () {
    const { fields: { message } } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="MessageComposer__container">
        <input 
          type="text"
          name="message"
          value={message}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.sendMessage}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

---

**EDIT**: Just saw that your fetch code includes JSX. WTF?

Try by changing the following:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  inputText: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>
})
```

with JSX-free version. It doesn't make any sense to do pass a React component as `JSON.stringify` isn't even able to serialize a function (ok you'll receive i.e 'Function' or '[Object object]' into `inputText` on your backend i guess).

Somthing like this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  inputText: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value
})
```

Also, if for any reason React doesn't find your ref (i.e. component returns `null` or any other reason), the `inputText` will either throw or return `undefined`.

If you refactor your code as I suggested above, you could do this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  inputText: this.state.fields.message
})
```

Comment: Refs aren't an antipattern (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Imagine having a massive form, in which case you'd be setting state on each `onChange`, and rerendering the entire form for every keystroke. In this case I agree, it would be better to use the pattern in your answer, but this can also have performance implications if _all_ the inputs are in the same `render` function.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but how can it solve the problem in which the data from the POST request doesn't appear in the chat ?

Comment: @Ben J, I suspected your approach to fail at setting value. Here you would do `this.setState({ message: data })`. Also, I was not very sure I did understand your problem and seen a opportunity to educate someone to better use React ;)

Comment: My problem is that the data from the Fetch operation doesn't appear in the chat UI, unlike the user input

Comment: @BenJ have you logged anything to your console in your `then` statements?

Comment: Yes,I added to the last then, It says that chats (that inside the console.log(chats)) is not defiend

Comment: @BenJ Updated my answer, I guess the issue was here.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem it was indeed a typo

Comment: @BenJ Can you do a `console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value)` just before the fetch? Can you confirm that you correctly receive the `inputText` value on your backend accordingly to what you wrote into this input?

Comment: The problem is in the "results" after ParsedJSON "Cannot read property 'results' of undefined", before that I do get the JSON from the API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fair amount to discuss regarding your code. To keep this answer simple and focused, I am just going to address your `fetch api call` and why you may not be seeing anything on the front end.

First, I suggest looking into Life Cycle Methods in the React Documentation. You can find that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class). If that link is broken, just go to React's documentation page and search "LifeCycle Methods".

The reason I bring that up is because you are `post`ing your data *every* time the component updates not when the user submits their chat message. So, the moment the user does submit you call your `onSubmit` function which calls `setState`. Setting the state will update the post. So anywhere in your code, when you make changes to your state or if there are changes to your component's props the DOM will update and `componentDidUpdate` will be triggered and you will post again.

Place your post api call in your `onSubmit` function. Update your form from this:

```
 submitMessage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        chats: this.state.chats.concat([

          {
            username: "clientUser",

            content: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>,

            img: "http://***.jpg"
          }
        ])
      },
      () => {

        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value = "";
      }
    );
  }
```

to this updated onSubmit function:

```
submitMessage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(
  "https://****",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"

    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      inputText: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>
    })
  }
).then(response => response.json())
  .then(parsedJSON => {
    parsedJSON.results.map((
      user
    ) => ({

      username: "BotResponse",
      content: `${user.message}',
      img: "http://***.jpg"
    }))
   }
  )
  .then(chats =>
    this.setState({
      chats
    })
  )
  .catch(error => console.log("parsing failed", error));

   //for the sake of readability and debugging, you might want to store 
   that obj in a local variable here and put that variable in place of ...[]
    this.setState(
      {
        chats: [
          ...this.state.chats,
          {
            username: "clientUser",

            content: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>,

            img: "http://***.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
      () => {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value = "";
      }
    );
  }
```

**Back-end**

You want to confirm that this is *actually* saving to your db (may seem obvious but double check that it is saving the way you want *and* that you are returning the correct info. in the correct format on your back-end. This could be where the problem is. Log your response to your back-end console and make sure it is returning everything correctly.

**Front-End**

Look at how you are setting your state in your fetch call. I'm not really sure how you are sending your data but here is an example of a post fetch call using axios.

```
axios.post("http://****", {
        data: this.state.data,
        more: this.state.more,
        etc: { example: "of", object: this.state.obj }
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          //do something with response.data
          //this.setState({ data: response.data})
        }
      });
```

There really isn't anything more I can suggest. I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with the source you have provided.

**Note**

There are a few things that you are doing throughout your code that I'm not sure you need to do. But, I did not address that in this answer because I'm not entirely sure what your project is and your desired results. But this should help with the issue of nothing rendering. If it doesn't, look into how you are setting your state in the `fetch api call`.

Hope this helps.

### EDIT

I don't believe you need to have three `.then` in your api call. Once you have parsed your json you can set your state there.

### EDIT 2

The above source was not giving the desired result. The fetch api call was not returning data to the second then call because the data from the first then call. Here is the updated `submitMessage` function.

```
submitMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(
      "https://****",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          inputText: <p>{ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value}</p>
        })
      }
    ).then(response => {
          return response.json() //here was the problem, nothing was being returned
       })
      .then(parsedJSON => {
        parsedJSON.results.map(user => ({
          username: "BotResponse",
          content: user.message, //this shouldn't need to be a string literal
          img: "http://***.jpg"
         })
        )
       }
      )
      .then(chats =>
        this.setState({
          chats
        })
      )
      .catch(error => console.log("parsing failed", error));
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I think there is a problem with brackets in the updated code in the set state, I am not sure what to fix there in that respect

Comment: let me take a look...just looked...do you mean in the `setState({ chats: [...this.state. })` part?

Comment: @BensSteves I've updated your sample to fix the setState brackets issue ;)

Comment: Unfortuanettly It didn't change the fact that it doesn't post messages in the UI from this Fetch operation.

Comment: may you log your state in your setState function after the api call. like this: setState({ keep your updates here}, console.log(this.state)); and see if the state is empty. also, log your `parsedJSON` to your console. are they both empty?

Comment: @Bens Steves The problem is in the "results" after ParsedJSON, error: "Cannot read property 'results' of undefined", before that I do get the JSON from the API

Comment: I have updated the answer. See under EDIT 2. That should be the ticket. :) let me know if that does not work.